# Falcon sensor fails to start the agent

Tags: security, network-security, penetration-tools

I am trying to install falcon-sensor(version:4.16.0) on a Debian machine. When I try to start the agent it doesn't start up.

I checked the logs of falcon-sensor and here is what it says : 
 2019 unable to initialize dynamic libraries.        (2309) [144]

I checked the log of falconctl and here is what it says : 
 Invalid file /opt/CrowdStrike/falconstore length: 0    (2277) [568]

I tried finding answers through googling but I could not find any.

Any help on this would be really helpful

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try running the below command and see what is the output sudo service falcon-sensor status

Answer (score 1):

falcon-sensor has `libssl.so.1.0.0` as dependency, but that version is missing on Debian Stretch (there is version 1.0.2).

I just created a symlink to the existing version:

```
ln -s libssl.so.1.0.2 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
```

and now it works.

Comment: You have to also set your CID. 
`/opt/CrowdStrike/falconctl -d --cid="<your CID>"`

Comment: -d is delete, to set it you want -s.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you performed the basic steps correctly:

1 ) Download `falcon-sensor.rpm` to your machine.
2 ) `sudo yum install -y falcon-sensor.rpm` .
3 )  `sudo /opt/CrowdStrike/falconctl -s --cid=<Your-CID>` .
4 )  `service falcon-sensor start`.

Check status:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-21-80-18 ~]$ service falcon-sensor status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status falcon-sensor.service
● falcon-sensor.service - CrowdStrike Falcon Sensor
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/falcon-sensor.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-09-05 13:48:34 UTC; 1min 6s ago
  Process: 2746 ExecStart=/opt/CrowdStrike/falcond (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2729 ExecStartPre=/opt/CrowdStrike/falconctl -g --cid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2747 (falcond)
    Tasks: 19
   Memory: 4.5M
   CGroup: /system.slice/falcon-sensor.service
           ├─2747 /opt/CrowdStrike/falcond
           └─2749 falcon-sensor

 systemd[1]: Starting CrowdStrike Falcon Sensor...
 falconctl[2729]: cid="<Your-CID>".
 falcond[2747]: starting
Started CrowdStrike Falcon Sensor.
 falcon-sensor[2749]: No traceLevel set via falconctl defaulting to none
 falcon-sensor[2749]: LogLevelUpdate: none = trace level 0.
```

View process:

```
ps -e | grep falcon-sensor
 2749 ?        00:00:00 falcon-sensor
```

Notice that all commands should be executed with `sudo` Or else you see the error below:

```
$ service falcon-sensor restart #< --- No root permission
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart falcon-sensor.service

Failed to restart falcon-sensor.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
See system logs and 'systemctl status falcon-sensor.service' for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason for falcon sensor to fail during start is because of incorrect CID being used/set.

Answer (score -1):

```
I follow install steps 1~3 below without issue, but have not get a CID, please let met know how to get it 

1 ) Download falcon-sensor.rpm to your machine.
2 ) sudo yum install -y falcon-sensor.rpm .
3 ) sudo /opt/CrowdStrike/falconctl -s --cid=<Your-CID>
4 ) service falcon-sensor start.
```